# wkhtmltoimage and images

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to use wkhtmltopdf to produce a PDF of an html file with images. Could someone please let me know how to get this to include the images. I have tried to do it with the following img tags

```
<img src="logo.jpg" alt="logo" />
<img src="http:\\localhost:7272\logo.jpg" alt="logo" />
<img src="C:/inetpub/testwebsite/logo.jpg" alt=logo" />
```

I am using a comandline:

```
wkhtmltopdf source.html destination.pdf
```

The html renders correctly, however there are no images.

My version is 0.11.0 rc2

Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it seems like it was this version that had the problem. I installed version 0.9.9 and it worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

Right, I just tried the simple example:

```
wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.com google.pdf
```

from the command line on my linux machine, and it works fine, even with no GUI.  I inspected the www.google.com webpage and that picture that it is rendering is using an `<img>` tag.

I am using version 0.11.0 rc1